# Nodejs Transform - can calling callback before push be considered good practice?

Tags: node.js, concurrency, nodejs-stream

Regarding the tranform function of stream.Transform:
Is it ok, in that it won't break something like the back-pressure mechanism,
and assuming I don't care about order, to call callback() before calling push() so that I can asynchronously process more than 1 chunk concurrently?

Specifically, I'd like to make asynchronous http requests.
I have a "url stream", and I want to push() the processed results for further processing/storage.

If I'll wait for the request to finish before calling callback(), I'll only have 1 request running each time.
If, however, I call callback while the request is on air:

```
request.get(url, (err, res) => push(process(res)));
return callback();
```

I can process many requests concurrently.

The code *seems* to work, but I wonder if I'm misusing stream.Transform and if I'm supposed to use something else entirely for this kind of pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

This breaks the design of streams.

If you don't care about back-pressure or the order of the stream, don't use a stream. Assuming your "url stream" is just a readable stream, directly consume it and stop using a stream at that point. You might also want to consider why you are using a stream of URLs but I don't want to judge too much.

As an example:

```
urlStream.on('data', (url) => {
  request.get(url, (err, res) => {
    // do whatever you want to do next.
  });
});
```

Comment: It’s a stream of urls becayse it’s a 2gig file of urls..  I actually do care about back-pressure as I need to write them to disk after. I tried a solution where I try and use the write flag/drain combo but it seemed to not work. That’s when I stumbled on using streams for this

Comment: I don't recommend using a transform stream here. You can use a read stream to acquire URLs and a write stream to write the responses to disk, but since you want to do parallel and don't care about the order, the middle part shouldn't be a transform stream.

Comment: So should I do the whole writer flag/pause read/onDrain combo?
That was what I originally tried but for some reason pause just didn't work and so it just kept on going and probably slowing itself down while losing data

Comment: I don't know if you should do the "whole writer flag/pause read/onDrain combo." In theory its just my example + `outputStream.write(stuff)` where I have the `do whatever you want to do next` comment.